# routing includes /index

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3

So I'm wondering in the `action_index()` function, why does kohana include the index word at the end of the url?

So it ends up being something like this: `controller_name/action_name` but I don't want `index` being there. How to disable if `action_index()`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make action optional in your route like this

```
Route::set('home', 'home(/<action>)')
        ->defaults(array(
            'controller' => 'Home',
            'action' => 'index'
        ));
```

now both `http://domain_name/home/index` and `http://domain_name/home` will trigger `action_index`.

Answer (score 0):

You can easly remove `index.php` from the url. Open the `application/bootstrap.php` file and set the `index_file` to `false`.

```
Kohana::init(array(
    'base_url' => '/kohana/',
    'index_file' => FALSE
));
```

Comment: "index" not "index.php"

Comment: If set, default action is `index` so you don't need it in the url. Check it in the `bootstrap.php` file.